# Could not find method getJMSDestination in class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue

Tags: java, ibm-mq, wrapper, tcserver, tanuki

We are getting below INFO message at splunk.

> [00004390] debug   [java  ] [messaging ] Could not find method
>   getJMSDestination in class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue.

I googled it but couldn't get proper clarity. https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/264880/jms-messages-in-websphere-native-stderrlog/

There is no `getJMSDestination()` method in `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue`. But `getJMSDestination()` method is available in `javax.jms.Message`

we are using tanuki wrapper with tc server. we are getting below INFO log at wrapper.log. Looks like it's JVM log but not sure why this info log are displaying in wrapper.log. any help here?

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/06/25 11:16:17 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/06/25 11:16:17 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/06/25 11:16:17 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/06/25 11:16:18 | Jun 25, 2018 11:16:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/06/25 11:16:18 | INFO: Initialization processed in 873 ms
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/06/25 11:16:19 | 2018-06-25 11:16:19 [000004a0] info    [native] License = license ok; 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/06/25 11:16:34 | Jun 25, 2018 11:16:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/06/25 11:16:34 | INFO: Server startup in 16173 ms
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/06/25 11:20:10 | 2018-06-25 11:20:10 [00001cb8] debug   [java  ] [messaging ] Could not find method getJMSDestination in class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/06/25 11:20:24 | 2018-06-25 11:20:24 [00001cb8] debug   [java  ] [messaging ] Could not find method getJMSDestination in class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that your MQ queue (com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue) is a JMS Endpoint, not a JMS Message. The closes method you have on a JMS queue is getQueueName().
If you want to actual message, your App should use the MQ message, not the queue itself